# Angular routing with multiple parameters, and some in the middle

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have the following route:

```
app/:foo/article/edit/:id
```

I was hoping I could navigate to this route by doing something like the following:

```
this.router.navigate(['app/:foo/article/edit/:id', 1, 3]);
```

But that doesn't work and I couldn't find any navigation or URL generation function for this purpose.

Do I realy need to replace the parameters myself?

EDIT:

I want to navigate programmatically because this is not the only route I want to navigate to. This is all done in a Route Guard and depending on the requirement I want to navigate to a different route. In the following another route:

```
app/:foo/material/wareneingang/edit/:id
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/app', 1, 'article', 'edit' 3]);
```

You can replace number values with variables as well.

EDIT:

If you want something closer to your approach you can try:

```
this.router.navigate(`app/${foo}/article/edit/${id}`);
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Yes, for the current case it would be a solution. However, I want to do the navigation programmatically. I have updated my question

Comment: You can use every element of route array as variable, but if you want something closer to your approach you can try:
this.router.navigate(`app/${foo}/article/edit/${id}`);
I updated answer.